# Threading in unity

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine

On button click I run method `Initialize()`.

```cs
private IEnumerator Initialize()
{
    Download download;
    download = new Download();

    StartCoroutine(download.LoadAsset("http://localhost/3dobjects?key=11","car13",(x)=>{j = x;}));
    yield return j;

    int k=download.GetRate(j)    
}
```

Second one (`GetRate`) depends on result from first method (`LoadAsset`), so it should run after `LoadAsset` finishes working.

But they run synchronously like in different thread, how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to

```
yield return StartCoroutine( ...
```

otherwise you won't be waiting for the coroutine to end.